# check file exists and return list of files in java?

Tags: java

My task is I am having a inputFileLocation and list of some config files and need to check those files exists at that location.

- Example: `inputfileLocation = C:/input`
- list of config files: `sample_a.conf, refund_a.conf, sample_b.conf, refund_b.conf`

Need to check whether the file exists and then return the list of `sample.conf` files and list of `refund.conf` files.

How to achieve this in java ?

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pretty simple:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.util.LinkedList;
import java.util.List;

public class FileFinder
{
    private String mInputFileLocation;
    private List<String> mSampleList;
    private List<String> mRefundList;

    public FileFinder(String inputFileLocation)
    {
        mInputFileLocation = inputFileLocation;
        mSampleList = new LinkedList<String>();
        mRefundList = new LinkedList<String>();
    }

    public void processList(List<String> filenameList)
    {
        for (String filename : filenameList)
        {
            File f = new File(mInputFileLocation, filename);
            if (f.exists())
            {
                if (filename.startsWith("sample_"))
                {
                    mSampleList.add(filename);
                }
                else if (filename.startsWith("refund_"))
                {
                    mRefundList.add(filename);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    public List<String> getSampleList()
    {
        return mSampleList;
    }

    public List<String> getRefundList()
    {
        return mRefundList;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thats great Brad.. this solves my problem , but one more thing instead of List<String> mSampleList ..can i used List<File> mSampleList. ?

Comment: Also, if you're happy with my answer, can you mark it as such by pressing the tick next to it?

Comment: Also, from the looks of things it seems you're pretty green to programming. I wouldn't suggest my solution if that's the case. You need to learn how to code from the ground up. 

Spend some time learning the basics. And please don't use this in any type of assignment, it will stick out like a sore thumb that it isn't your code.

Comment: I am getting the error when converting List<String> to List<File> at mSampleList.add(filename),  the requirement is fileNameList will be List<String> but the mSampleList and mRefundList has to List<File>

Comment: This is why you need to actually understand the code you're using.
Read about Java Generics then take another look at the code.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/12988/discussion-between-brad-and-beginner)

Answer (score 3):

Use `java.io.File` class. It has methods:

- `exists()`

  > Tests whether the file or directory denoted by this abstract pathname exists.
- `list(FilenameFilter)`

  > Returns an array of strings naming the files and directories in the directory denoted by this abstract pathname that satisfy the specified filter.

Comment: @Beginner, you should try it yourself first as that is defintely the best way to learn. If you try and fail, post what you have attempted and you will find people more willing to help.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I would do it:

1. Check that the file exists using the [`exists()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#exists%28%29) method;
2. Check that the file is a directory using the [`isDirectory()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/File.html#isDirectory%28%29)
   method;
3. Obtain the files using Apache Commons [`iterateFiles()`](http://commons.apache.org/io/api-release/org/apache/commons/io/FileUtils.html#iterateFiles%28java.io.File,%20java.lang.String%5B%5D,%20boolean%29) method.

Answer (score 0):

```
        File path = new File("C:/input");


        // Get the list of files in the directory
        File [] files = path.listFiles();

        for (int i = 0; i < files.length; i++){
            // Check whether files[i] is a file. If it is a file, it will print it.
            if (files[i].isFile()){ 
                System.out.println(files[i]);
            }
        }
```